# Python Pandas trying to get the mode with my other statitics

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have csv data:

```
Class,  Code,   Vendor, State,  NumberOfDays
3,      123,    Name1,  NE,     12.58402778
1,      876,    Name2,  TX,     12.51041667
3,      123,    Name1,  NE,     2.354166667
1,      876,    Name2,  TX,     12.21111111
3,      456,    Name2,  NY,     6.346527778
2,      876,    Name1,  NY,     5.513194444
3,      123,    Name1,  NE,     5.38125
1,      876,    Name2,  TX,     5.409722222
```

And I have the follow code that gives me the `mean`, `min`, `max` and `median` of the `NumberOfDays` field based on groupings of the other fields

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:...input.csv')

d = {'mean':'AverageDays','min':'LowestNumberOfDays','max':'HighestNumberOfDays','median':'MedianDays'}
df = (df.groupby(['Class','Code','Vendor','State'])['NumberOfDays']
    .agg(['mean','min','max','median'])
    .rename(columns=d)
    .reset_index())
df.to_csv(r'C:...output.csv', index=False)
```

It does what I need perfectly:

```
Class,Code,Vendor,State,AverageDays,LowestNumberOfDays,HighestNumberOfDays,MedianDays
1,876,Name2,TX,10.043750000666666,5.409722222,12.51041667,12.21111111
2,876,Name1,NY,5.513194444,5.513194444,5.513194444,5.513194444
3,123,Name1,NE,6.773148149,2.354166667,12.58402778,5.38125
3,456,Name2,NY,6.346527778,6.346527778,6.346527778,6.346527778
```

When I add `mode` to the code:

```
d = {'mean':'AverageDays','min':'LowestNumberOfDays','max':'HighestNumberOfDays','median':'MedianDays','mode':'ModeDays'}
df = (df.groupby(['Class','Code','Vendor','State'])['NumberOfDays']
    .agg(['mean','min','max','median','mode'])
```

I get this errror:

AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'mode' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

When I researched this I see that mode is not a natural function in pandas but my issue is I cannot figure out how to leverage the other ways to calculate mode, and incorporate it in this same step of the code since this step reduces my data set into condensed groups. So I cannot run it after and if I run it before I will need to apply the mode value repeatedly across all the rows of my data for each group. My data is already over 4 gig and 30 million records so I would like to avoid making it bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use value_counts for mode

```
d = {'mean':'AverageDays','min':'LowestNumberOfDays','max':'HighestNumberOfDays','median':'MedianDays', '<lambda>': 'ModeDays'}

df.groupby(['Class','Code','Vendor','State'])['NumberOfDays']\
    .agg(['mean','min','max','median', lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]])\
    .rename(columns=d)\
    .reset_index()


    Class   Code    Vendor  State   AverageDays LowestNumberOfDays  HighestNumberOfDays MedianDays  ModeDays
0   1       876     Name2   TX      10.043750   5.409722    12.510417   12.211111   12.510417
1   2       876     Name1   NY      5.513194    5.513194    5.513194    5.513194    5.513194
2   3       123     Name1   NE      6.773148    2.354167    12.584028   5.381250    2.354167
3   3       456     Name2   NY      6.346528    6.346528    6.346528    6.346528    6.346528
```

Answer (score 1):

You still can do that 
`lambda x: x.mode()[0]`

```
df.groupby(['Class','  Code','   Vendor',' State'])['  NumberOfDays'].agg(['mean','min','max','median',lambda x: x.mode()[0]])
Out[8]: 
                                    mean       min        max     median  \
Class   Code    Vendor  State                                              
1     876        Name2   TX    10.043750  5.409722  12.510417  12.211111   
2     876        Name1   NY     5.513194  5.513194   5.513194   5.513194   
3     123        Name1   NE     6.773148  2.354167  12.584028   5.381250   
      456        Name2   NY     6.346528  6.346528   6.346528   6.346528   
                               <lambda>  
Class   Code    Vendor  State            
1     876        Name2   TX    5.409722  
2     876        Name1   NY    5.513194  
3     123        Name1   NE    2.354167  
      456        Name2   NY    6.346528
```

Comment: I remember there is some way to specify the name of the col rather than lambda...

Comment: @BradSolomon you mean `agg({'somename':func})`?

Comment: @BradSolomon dictionary renaming in agg was deprecated in Pandas version 0.19.0 I believe.  In short, you used to could do that now you have to do differently.

Comment: Yeah, that's what it looks like @ScottBoston

Comment: @BradSolomon right now I most of time we using `rename` . or rebuild the DataFrame

Comment: @Wen True, `.rename(columns={'<lambda>':'mode'})` should work in this case

Comment: @Bharathshetty why ? He is asking for `mode` , And number all unique , which mean all of them are `mode` , It is depends on the which one he want , `value_counts` here  sort key, so it will give back the first sorted one

Comment: Couldn't disagree with this either. Well I take back by comment